# Trouble making stateful React components work together

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a React App and i'm struggling to get the basic functionality of components with state working. So far i've got a home page that connects to a registration page, when I click to the registration page I can handle user input. The registration is the class component I am trying to use state in so far.

I've set up a pretty basic process so far in this component just to see if it works. But when I click the button to console log what is currently stored the entire page reloads as if nothing has happened.

A very basic display of what it currently looks like:

```
import registerUser from './user.js';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Route path='/register' component={registerUser}/>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

```
class registerUser extends Component {
handleChange = () => {
    console.log('test');
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
             <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Click</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default registerUser;
```

But as I mentioned when I click the button the entire page just reloads as if nothing has occured. Am I missing something something basic as to why trying to use this method in a separate component reloads the entire app?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `form` anywhere?

Comment: Why do you have two `export default` in the same file? Also, why isn't `handleChange` a normal function, with that button `onclick={ evt => this.handleChange(evt)}`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, OP has 2 different files, Check the import

Comment: If this is your only setup, then this code should work. If you have other code and not posted here then do post it also. One suggestion is, React component name should be in `PascalCase`, so just replace `registerUser` to `RegisterUser`.

Comment: Apologies wasn't specific enough, they're in two separate files. It's imported and opened using the router. But yeah as soon as I click the button the console log basically flashes the word and then the page reloads.

Comment: Can you reproduce that in a codepen?

Comment: Okay, so I've found some of the issue. It was actually inside a form, if the button is inside the form the page reloads.

Comment: Recreate it in the codesandbox please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is inside a form, then you must write `e.preventDefault()` in your `handleChange` function,

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();  //It will prevent form submit
    console.log('test');
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nwuxzj)

**Note:** React component name should be in `PascalCase`, so just replace `registerUser` to `RegisterUser`.